# IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory while using Apache CXF to call REST url

Tags: java, apache, maven, jax-rs, cxf

> I am creating a web client by Apache cxf for calling one rest URL,
>   when I have tested my code through main class , its giving me proper
>   response, but when I deployed it in was 8.5 server, its giving error.

```
[10/1/15 10:32:45:461 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory
[10/1/15 10:32:45:462 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:463 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:331)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:463 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:155)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:463 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:856)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:464 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:464 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:465 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:465 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:466 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:331)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:466 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:155)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:467 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:856)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:467 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:468 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:469 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
[10/1/15 10:32:45:469 CDT] 000000ce SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:164)
```

> I have updated my POM with neethi 3.0.3 and apache cxf bundle 2.7.9.
>   but still error is coming, what else can I do here ?, Thanks !!

Comment: I even tried to make web module to load parent last , it started to give me a lot of exceptions for jar, while starting the ear , do I have to make them exclude from POM ?

Comment: Which websphere server do you use ? Liberty ? ND ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have packaged something into your archive which is already on the server.

Just do not package any implementation or API of a technology that is part of Java EE into your archive (WAR/EAR).

Google for "Java EE full profile" and "Java EE web profile" and it should give you and overview of which technologies are part of the Java EE profiles and as such **must** be supported in Java EE compliant servers. JAX-RS (Java API for RESTful Web Services) is part of full profile.

You can use `<scope>provided</scope>` or even better `<scope>test</scope>` to prevent any dependency from being packaged.
I say test is even better because in that way you are prevented from accidentally programming against an implementation.

As you naturally need to program against APIs you define APIs as `provided`:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

I am giving you this jboss thing because that is the only collection of Java EE APIs that has sources and javadoc attached - for your IDE viewing pleasure.